# Unauthorized error when invoking API endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been scrambling for answers to solve my API issue.
I am trying to restrict access to my API by providing API key whenever the API endpoint URL is invoked. Without API key I am able to successfully invoke my gateway endpoint URL.

```
https://xxxxxxxx6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/pets
```

But when I added API key to my resource, it started to fall apart with "Forbidden" error when I invoke the URL like this.

```
https://xxxxxxxx6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/pets?key=abcdef
```

Below are my resources.

```
MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Currently does not support S3 upload event.
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.12
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
        - "${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-get-v1"
        - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
          TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
    CodeUri: .
    MemorySize: 10240
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Events:
      MyPetsAPIEvent:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId:
            Ref: MyApiGateway
          Path: /pets
          Method: GET
          RequestParameters:
            - method.request.header.Authorization:
                Required: true
                Caching: true
    Tracing: Active


MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Variables:
      stageName: test
    Name:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-api'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
    Cors:
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
      AllowMethods: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    StageName: test
    Auth:
      ApiKeyRequired: true
      UsagePlan:
        CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
        UsagePlanName: "my_api_batch"
        ResourcePolicy:
        CustomStatements:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
            Resource: "execute-api:/test/GET/pets"
```

This is the role attached to my API (FunctionInvokeRole)

```
MyLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                - 'batch:SubmitJob'
                - 'batch:DescribeJobs'
                - 'batch:CancelJob'
                - 'apiGateway:Invoke'
                - 'S3:*'
              Resource: "*"
```

This is my lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  print('event ====> ', event)
  print(event['resource'])
  api_key = event['queryStringParameters']['key']
  print('api_key = ', api_key)
  route = event['resource']
  jobQueue = "dev-myjobQueue-api"
  batch_client = boto3.client('batch')

  if route == '/pets':
    response = batch_client.submit_job(
        jobDefinition='pets-job-def',
        jobName='pets-job-name',
        jobQueue=jobQueue,
    )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('AWS Batch job submitted successfully.')
    }
```

As you can see the lambda function just invokes a batch job depending on the route name provided in the URL (pets in this case)

I have no idea what else I am missing here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-key-source.html):

> Your API Gateway API can receive API keys from one of two sources:
>
> `HEADER`
>
> You distribute API keys to your customers and require them to pass the API key as the `X-API-Key` header of each incoming request.
>
> …

Hence, you should pass your api key in the header.

If you absolutely need it passed in the query parameter, you'll have to create a custom authorizer as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/accepting-api-keys-as-a-query-string-in-amazon-api-gateway/).

---

As a side note, it seems that the only thing your lambda is doing is invoke the Batch job. You don't need a lambda for it at all. You can just create a [request mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) to convert your query parameters to a Batch request, and hook up Batch as a native AWS integration target.

Comment: Thank you. I've 2 questions on this. 1) you mean to say I don't need the lambda function at all ?(AWS::Serverless::Function block). If I remove that how do I integrate my API to invoke AWS batch? 2) You mentioned HEADER and X-API-Key. I have setup API key with my API gateway. When calling I append the API key as https://xxxxxx6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/pets?key=abcd. Is this the correct way of invoking the API with API key? Thanks.

Comment: @Ram: 1. no, you don't need the lambda. 1.1. You create a mapping template and integrate your endpoint with Batch directly. 2. You pass it in the header `X-API-Key`. Note that my answer does contain answers to all those questions. If you have follow-up questions, please ask them separately. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have more than 10 different routes to my API and I find it easy to maintain them with a lambda function. Meanwhile I was thinking of restricting the API access by providing SourceIp condition within my AWS::Serverless::Api block. There is a sourceIp I could see when I printed the event from the lambda function. There is also a "X-Forwarded-For" IP address that is shown in the event and they both are same. Just wondering if I could these Ip address in my condition block to restrict API access? Not sure if that is a preferred way of doing this.

Comment: @Ram: these are all interesting questions, but they don't have anything to do with your original post. This is not a discussion forum. If you have separate questions (as I see you do, and they look like good questions), please ask them in separate posts. Thank you.

Comment: understood. Will raise a new one

Comment: @Ram: do you know what an HTTP header is? Did you try setting the header `X-API-Key` in your request to API Gateway? What happened when you did?

Comment: I did set ApiKeySourceType: HEADER in my Api (Also created API key). But I am not clear on how to make the API call restrict from a browser using the key. I tried adding headers to my lambda code but no luck. I just keep getting "Forbidden" when I invoke the API from the browser. thanks

Comment: @Ram: http headers and working with them is the foundational skill for every web developer. Instead of inventing insecure access control methods, I suggest that you read up on that, or ask it as a question here (it will probably be closed as a duplicate though).

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could if I am a web developer.