# Using Source IP to control access to API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am looking at list of possible ways to control access to API gateway. I tried using API keys and other means but I was not successful. See original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828013/unauthorized-error-when-invoking-api-endpoint-url/77828087?noredirect=1#comment137217922_77828087)

I then came across a way of allowing only specific IP address to access API gateway and I included this under "ResourcePolicy" when creating API.
For the IP address, whenever I print the event from my lambda function, it prints a specific IP address for "sourceIp" and "X-Forwarded-For" parameters.

So I tried using this IP in my ResourcePolicy as below.

```
MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    AccessLogSetting:
      DestinationArn: !GetAtt MyLogGroupForApi.Arn
      Format: $context.extendedRequestId $context.identity.sourceIp $context.identity.caller 
$context.identity.user [$context.requestTime] "$context.httpMethod $context.resourcePath 
$context.protocol" $context.status $context.responseLength $context.requestId
    Variables:
      stageName: test
        Name:
          !Sub
          - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-api'
          - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
            TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
     TracingEnabled: true
     OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
     Cors:
       AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
       AllowMethods: "'*'"
       AllowOrigin: "'*'"
     StageName: test
     Auth:
       ResourcePolicy:
        CustomStatements:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
            Resource: "execute-api:/test/GET/pets"
            Condition:
              IpAddress:
                aws:SourceIp:
                  - **"201.02.02.002"**
```

As you can see this is the IP address that I am seeing when I print the lambda event.
Having this IP here worked fine me, so when I tried to reach the API gateway from my personal computer, I get "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform execute-api:Invoke on resource:".

Whereas when I tried the API gateway from my official computer, I am able to successfully launch the API gateway URL which is what I wanted.

Now the question is:
Where does this IP address come from? Can I rely on the IP address to restrict access to API?
If this IP is not a static IP, then I can't use it, so I am back to square one.

Any help in understanding this is much appreciated.

Comment: A device's IP address is usually (not always) assigned by the network it's connected to. The protocol that assigns addresses may assign different addresses on successive connections. Those addresses may further be obscured by NAT or VPN or other systems. Relying on IP addresses for authentication is likely to end in tears.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the question is: Where does this IP address come from?

The data in `X-Forwarded-From` is one or more comma-separated IP addresses. They may come from your client, CloudFront or Application Load Balancer (if you are using any of those). API gateway just adds its own headers to whatever it receives from upstream. If your client sends a white-listed request in that header, it will get blindly passed to the integration lambda.

The data in `requestContext.identity.sourceIp` has the source IP address of the entity that created a TCP connection to your API Gateway, over which the HTTP data for the request is coming. Again, it might be CloudFront or Application Balancer if you're using them.

> Can I rely on the IP address to restrict access to API?

Short answer: no.

A longer answer is "maybe, if you control the IP address". In the public segment of the internet you, for all practical purposes, don't.

---

> I tried using API keys and other means but I was not successful. See original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828013/unauthorized-error-when-invoking-api-endpoint-url).

The API keys (or other form of autorization) is the right way to restrict access.

In the post you've linked you described how you passed your API key in an incorrect way, and my answer (basically, a copy-paste from the AWS docs) describes the right way to do that. I'm not sure why you were "not successful", provided that you did follow the direction in the answer.